# Alternative (pref. mature) Linux PAM authentication methods?

Tags: linux, authentication, pam

I'm looking for alternative, non-keyboard-password authentication methods to unlock my laptop. Whatever authentication it is, it should be quick and convenient to perform and relatively secure. Yes, subjective criteria, I know. Think Android-style shape drawing gesture, though. It would fit that criteria. Or perhaps activate webcam for face recognition?

Unfortunately this Samsung S9 doesn't have a fingerprint reader nor NFC. It does have a multitouch clickpad/touchpad, webcam, bluetooth. There's [pam_blue](https://bitbucket.org/ur6lad/pam_blue), which I've experimented with, but it turned out to be too unmaintained to properly work with recent PAM versions. Idea was to make bluetooth phone visible and pam_blue would scan the local area for known devices.

How to choose the answer for this question? I'd say the main criteria would be general accessibility for accomplishing the goal, considering the restraints set by the device and being a PAM module. IE I can't pick a solution as an answer if it requires purchasing some $1000 magic dongle or similar.

Comment: try yubikey. They do some that are smartphone friendly.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have the original Yubikey for my looooong password. That's exactly what I'm trying to simplify for low-risk situations, i.e. going out to lunch at work :)

Comment: the newer neo one should do what you want. I only have the original ones myself.

Comment: Yes, the NFC-enabled NEO is an interesting one. I'm having trouble visualizing the process in my head atm. I guess it also doesn't fall under the "mature" requirement too well, but I definitely appreciate you making me browse through their current portfolio.

I think I'm going to look for some mini-size NFC USB dongle next.

Comment: Package `libpam-blue` is included in Ubuntu 13.04. Does it not work?

Comment: I have seen no updates to pam_blue since I worked with it.